# Phone number in menu (only on mobiles)

Tags: html, css

i wanna add phone number to menu of my website (only on mobile) and after touching on that number it will make a call. So far i´ve got this

First- this is HTML code of menu

```
          <div class="rd-navbar-panel">
            <button data-rd-navbar-toggle=".rd-navbar-nav-wrap" 
            type="submit" class="rd-navbar-toggle toggle-original"><span>
            </span></button>
           <div class="rd-navbar-brand"><a href="index.html" class="brand-
            name">    
            <img src="logo.png" style="width: 80px">                
             </a></div><a href="index.html" class="brand-name">
             </a>
           </div>
```

And this is what i wanna put in

```
 <a href="tel:+1800229933">+1800229933</a>
```

But when i put it in it wont show up on mobiles. How to make it work? Thanks
If you need to see something else from the code here is link on my site: http://testwebsites.9e.cz/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is z-index. 
On mobile .rd-navbar-brand is covering your mobile phone anchor tag since it has higher z-index.

Try

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
.rd-navbar-brand {
position: relative;
left: 0;
}
```

And add z-index: 1 to your mobile phone anchor tag.

Comment: Thank youu! But on right side of that menu its not visible. http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//testwebsites.9e.cz/index.html&w=320&h=568&a=37&s=1

Comment: But it works except that thing. How to make it visible on that right side too?

Comment: In your CSS change styling for .rd-navbar-fixed to the following:

.rd-navbar-fixed .rd-navbar-brand {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 46px;
    height: 51px;
    z-index: 17;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="address-group">
 <a href="index.html" class="brand-name"></a>
 <a id="mail" href="mailto:#" class="fa-envelope-o">info@demolink.org</a>
 <a id="mobileNo" href="tel:+1800229933">
   <i class="fa-mobile-phone"></i>
   <span> +1800229933</span>
 </a>
</div>
```

---

```
#mobileNo{display:none;}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   .rd-navbar-brand {
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
    }
    #mobileNo{display:block!important;}
    #mail{display:none;}
}
```